# Jquery stop function no works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create this function for show div with function call , but i nedd execute this function and stop in one second after show :

```
<script>

function repit_clouds(request)
{
  if (request=='no')
  {
    stop();
  }
  else
  {
    if (request=='ok')
    {
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#header_sun").fadeIn(4000);
        $("#header_sun").fadeOut(4000);
      },10000);
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{

  $("#header_sun").fadeIn(4000).delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
  repit_clouds('ok');
  $("#header_background_clouds").fadeOut(2000).css("display","#none");
  $("#header_background_night").fadeIn(2000).css("background","#000").show(4000).fadeIn(2500);
  repit_clouds('no');
});
</script>
```

The problem it´s with repit_clouds function , when i send the value no the function must stop , but no works fine and continue as if the `request==ok` , i don´t know why no stop

Comment: Did you read how [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) works? read teh documentation!

Comment: @mt.VVoo nice formatting - shame the OP's code is probably not formatted at all ;-)

Answer (score 2):

umm, what *exactly* do you think `stop()` does?  Did you perhaps mean:

```
$('#header_sun').stop()
```

which would pause any existing animations on that element?

Or did you perhaps also want to stop the interval timer:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

which of course also requires that `interval` be declared *outside* of the function so that its value isn't lost each time you call the function.

I note also that your `.css()` functions won't be queued by the `.fadeOut()` or `.show()` calls - `.css()` isn't an animation function so those changes will always happen immediately.

Likewise the two calls to `repit_clouds()` won't be queued either - if you expect those to be done *after* the previous animations then you need to investigate the jQuery `.queue()` function, or trigger them during "animation complete callbacks".

Comment: Only i want stop function no more